# how to convert a list of dictionary to one dicarionary

Tags: python, dictionary

Right now i have this:

```
A={0:[{1:2},{2:3}],
   1:[{4:5},{5:6}]}
```

And I want to change this dictionary to the following:

```
A={0:{1:2,2:3},
   1:{4:5,5:6}}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it's possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: tell us what you have tried yet so than we can help you at the point where you are stuck

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: Iterate over the elements int the list and merge them into `temp_dict`. assign `temp_dict` to the key of the original dictionary.

```
A={0:[{1:2},{2:3}],
   1:[{4:5},{5:6}]}


for k,v in A.items():
    temp_dict={}
    for elem in v:
        for k2,v2 in elem.items():
            temp_dict[k2] = v2
    A[k] = temp_dict

print A

# prints {0: {1: 2, 2: 3}, 1: {4: 5, 5: 6}}
```